# Shinydashboard: tabPanel sidebar inside tabBox

Tags: shiny, shinydashboard

I am trying to create a sidebar effect inside a `tabBox` for a particular `tabPanel` (very similar to how `shinyDashboardPlus` does it with just a [box](https://rinterface.com/shiny/shinydashboardPlus/)) but it's not turning out as expected using `mainPanel` and `sidebarPanel`.

Code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)


  header <- dashboardHeader()
  sidebar <- dashboardSidebar()

  body <- dashboardBody(
    useShinyjs(),
    fluidRow(
      div(id = "TimingBox",
          tabBox(id = "Timing",
                 tabPanel("Tab 1", 
                          mainPanel(
                            plotOutput("plot1")
                          ),
                          div(id ="Sidebar",
                            sidebarPanel(
                            "Look here"
                            )
                          )
                 ),
                 tabPanel("Tab 2"),
                 title = p("Status",actionLink("Link", NULL, icon = icon("plus-square-o"))), width = 4,
                 selected = "Tab 1"
          )
      )
    )
  )

  ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)

server <- function(input, output) {

  shinyjs::hide(id = "Sidebar")

  observeEvent(input$Link, {
    shinyjs::toggle(id = "Sidebar")
  })


  set.seed(122)
  histdata <- rnorm(500)

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    data <- histdata[seq_len(50)]
    hist(data)
  })


}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

ShinyDashboardPlus's box with sidebar (clicks on the i symbol):

[image]
[image]

Updated code:

I've worked on it some bit and realized I was missing `sidebarLayout`(). However, I would still like

1. The sideBar to overlay on top of the mainPanel
2. Have the sideBar height be the same as the mainPanel.

   ```
   library(shiny)
   library(shinydashboard)


     header <- dashboardHeader()
     sidebar <- dashboardSidebar()

     body <- dashboardBody(
       useShinyjs(),
       fluidRow(
         div(id = "TimingBox",
             tabBox(id = "Timing",
                    tabPanel("Tab 1", 
                       sidebarLayout(
                         div(id = "Sidebar",
                             style = "z-index: 1000;",
                             sidebarPanel("There are currently 20 overdue here", width = 6)
                         ),

                         mainPanel(plotOutput("plot1"), width = 12)
                       )
                    ),
                    tabPanel("Tab 2"),
                    title = p("Status",actionLink("Link", NULL, icon = icon("plus-square-o")),actionLink("Link2", NULL, icon = icon("search"))), width = 4,
                    selected = "Tab 1"
             )
         )
       )
     )

     ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)

   server <- function(input, output) {

     shinyjs::hide(id = "Sidebar")

     observeEvent(input$Link, {
       shinyjs::toggle(id = "Sidebar")
     })


     set.seed(122)
     histdata <- rnorm(500)

     output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
       data <- histdata[seq_len(50)]
       hist(data)
     })


   }

   shinyApp(ui, server)
   ```

Comment: Could you clarify some elements please : do you want the plot to reduce its width when the sidebar appear ? Does the button have to appear only when tab1 is selected and be on the header ? ?

Comment: I would think sidebar would want to overlay the plot (i.e. plot is not reduced) and the button doesn't have to only appear when tab1 is selected but that would be cherries on top!

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to use shinydashboardPlus ? I have a solution using shinyWidgets, I am writing it

Comment: I would love to use shinydashboardPlus! I am using it currently for my boxes but I didn't see a Plus enhancement for tabBox.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using a `dropdownButton` from `shinyWidgets`. I think you can easily have "Status" and the button aligned by using some additional CSS.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinyWidgets)


header <- dashboardHeader()
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar()

body <- dashboardBody(
  useShinyjs(),
  fluidRow(
    div(id = "TimingBox",
        tabBox(id = "Timing",
               tabPanel("Tab 1", 
                  plotOutput("plot1")

               ),
               tabPanel("Tab 2"),
               title = p("Status",
                         div(id = "mybutton", 
                             # put the button in div so it can be hide/show with some shinyjs
                             dropdownButton(
                               "A title", 
                               textInput("id1", "an input"),
                               selectInput("id2", "another input", choices = letters[1:5]),
                               circle = TRUE,
                               size = 'xs',
                               right = TRUE,
                               icon = icon("gear"),
                               width = '100px'
                         ))), 
               width = 4,
               selected = "Tab 1"
        )
    )
  )
)

ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)

server <- function(input, output) {

  set.seed(122)
  histdata <- rnorm(500)

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    data <- histdata[seq_len(50)]
    hist(data)
  })

  # Display button to show the sidebar only when tab 1 is active
  observe({
    print(input$Timing)
    if(input$Timing != "Tab 1"){
      shinyjs::hide(id = "mybutton")
    }else{
      shinyjs::show(id = "mybutton")
    }
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: The dropdown doesn't really solve the look of it. Really looking for more of a sidebar UI